# Difference between ":" and "|" in R linear modeling

Tags: r, operators

When constructing a linear model in R, what is the difference between the following two statements:

```
lm(y ~ x | z)
lm(y ~ x : z)
```

The [`lm` function documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) documents the `:` operator as follows:

> A specification of the form first:second indicates the set of terms obtained by taking the interactions of all terms in first with all terms in second.

There's no mention of `|` syntax on that page. What is the difference?

Comment: | is only used in conditional models and anova and hence makes no sense in a lm call. Actually there should be an error thrown.

Comment: Nope, works perfectly fine for numerical data. Doesn't work for factor data, though. I'm using "R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)", according to `R.Version()`.

Comment: If | doesn't error in `lm`, I bet it's because it's actually evaluating a logical "or" on the data that is getting coerced back to a numeric.

Comment: @John - good thinking, and that is likely why it doesn't work for factors, as they're all dummy variables, which can't be coerced the same way.

Comment: You can find all operators here ?formula.

Comment: @eykanal I know it doesn't throw an error. I was just voicing a sentiment, as in 'I believe the lm function should check for that and tell you that you are trying something that doesn't really make sense.'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:` is used for interactions.  In your example `lm(y ~ x : z)`, the formula means "y is dependent upon an interaction effect between `x` and `z`.

Usually, you wouldn't include an interaction in a linear regression like this unless you also included the individual terms `x` and `z` as well.  `x * z` is short for `x + x:z + z`.

AFAIK, `|` isn't used by `lm` at all.  It certainly doesn't show up in any of the examples in `demo("lm.glm", "stats")`.  It is used in the mixed effects models in the `nlme` package.

An example from `?intervals.lme`:

```
model <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
ranef(model)
```

Here the `|` means "group by".  That is, a different random effect for age is fitted for every subject.  (Looking at `ranef(model)`, you can see that each row corresponds to the random effects for a person (subject).)

Comment: Nice answer, but can you detail the "a different random effect for age is fitted for every subject", please? It is not very clear to me... Thanks

Comment: Is there a difference between `lm(y ~ x + x:z + z + k)` and `lm(y ~ x*z + k)`?

Comment: @sop They are the same thing.  Try it with a real dataset if you need to be convinced.