# What is the best way to add vars to linear model if they depends one fo the other in R?

Tags: r

I have a data that has 3 variables that depend one of the other, like a hierarchy, so supposing that the data look like this:

```
 H0   H1   H2   t   y   x
 a    a1   a1a  5   2   1
 a    a1   a1b  5   4   2
 a    a2   a2a  8   3   3
 b    b1   b1a  22  7   88
 c    a1   c1a  2   2   2
 ...
```

As it can be seen, there is a hierarchy: H0->H1->H2. And there maybe the same H1 for two different H0. I want to make a linear model for x depending on the other variables:

```
model <- lm(log(x) ~ H0 + H1 + H2 + t + y)
```

This has worked, but if I change it with `H0*H1 + H2 + t + y` I get an not enough memory error. And if I do `H0 + H1 + H0:H1 + H2 + t + y` I get the same error with the same estimated needed size (that I assume is correct).

I have seen also that there is also nesting `/` and conditioning `|` ([docs](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/formulae.html)), and I am not really sure which is the best for my case. I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297145/difference-between-and-in-r-linear-modeling#9297849) that

> `|` isn't used by `lm` at all

which I am afraid to agree, but no conter arguments. And there are also as is `I(...)` and also `^`, and I really want some more explanations about these approaches.

More: supposing that I have another variable q, that I do not use in the model shall I use `-q` in `lm`?

Comment: My guess is that you have a huge amount of factor levels, which result in a huge design matrix. You can run easily run out of memory in such a case.

Comment: so, what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Calculate how many levels `H0:H1` means and try something like `lm.fit.sparse` in package MatrixModels. But you should probably look for a different statistical method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The - operator removes the specified terms, so that (a+b+c)^2 - a:b is identical to a + b + c + b:c + a:c.

It could also be used to delete the intercept term.

Comment: Ok, so this is the - operator used for lm, but can you also tell me about / and | ?